# Remoting channel creation options values not set on Channel

Tags: jboss-eap-7

I am running EAP 7.1.0 CR2 and have seen something odd in the channel creation options for remoting connections. For remote EJB calls. The options configuration is not being set on the xnio layer. I found the TCP_NODELAY property is not set on the Channel to the value I specified when it is created.

In my standalone-full.xml file my remoting connection XNIO properties are set with

```
<remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="ejbWorker">
    <channel-creation-options>
        <option name="READ_TIMEOUT" value="${prop.remoting-connector.read.timeout:20}" type="xnio"/>
        <option name="TCP_NODELAY" value="false" type="xnio"/>
        <option name="WORKER_READ_THREADS" value="2" type="xnio"/>
        <option name="WORKER_WRITE_THREADS" value="2" type="xnio"/>
        <option name="MAX_INBOUND_MESSAGES" value="300" type="remoting"/>
        <option name="MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES" value="300" type="remoting"/>
    </channel-creation-options>
</remote>
```

I'd expect the remoting subsystem to set these. But TRACE logging on XNIO shows it does not. Here is the log messages.

```
2017-11-22 19:42:20,170 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: JBoss EAP 7.1.0.GA (WildFly Core 3.0.3.Final-redhat-1) started in 265750ms - Started 1371 of 1652 services (502 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
2017-11-22 19:43:22,937 TRACE [org.jboss.remoting.remote.connection] (ejbWorker I/O-2) Initialized connection from /192.168.0.4:48861 to /192.168.0.4:8084 with options {org.xnio.Options.TCP_NODELAY=>true,org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.SASL_PROTOCOL=
>remote,org.xnio.Options.REUSE_ADDRESSES=>true}
```

Looking at the code in the wildfly-core remoting subsystem the org.jboss.as.remoting.HttpConnectorAdd.launchServices method uses org.jboss.as.remoting.ConnectorUtils.getFullOptions to obtain a Map of properties. Defaulted to this

```
{org.jboss.remoting3.RemotingOptions.SASL_PROTOCOL=>remote,org.xnio.Options.TCP_NODELAY=>true,org.xnio.Options.REUSE_ADDRESSES=>true}
```

I would expect the OptionsMap to be updated. With the settings in the channel creation options. Am I wrong to expect this ?

Regards,
Jeremy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCP_NODELAY socket option cannot be disabled as doing so will interfere with the correct operation of the Remoting protocol.

I did explore using TCP_CORK instead on Linux to improve throughput without sacrificing latency, and it did seem to work well, however it would require a finished and well-tested native XNIO implementation which is (at best) a side experiment at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The EJB subsystem remote/channel-creation-options settings don't go through `org.jboss.as.remoting.HttpConnectorAdd`. They get passed in to `org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteConnectorService` where they are passed in to a remoting `Endpoint.registerService` call. AFAICT they only options that are read from the OptionMap passed in to that method are

- RemotingOptions.TRANSMIT_WINDOW_SIZE,
- RemotingOptions.MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGES
- RemotingOptions.RECEIVE_WINDOW_SIZE
- RemotingOptions.MAX_INBOUND_MESSAGES
- RemotingOptions.MAX_OUTBOUND_MESSAGE_SIZE
- RemotingOptions.MAX_INBOUND_MESSAGE_SIZE.

This is done by `org.jboss.remoting3.remote.RemoteReadListener` as it sets up a Channel after a channel-open request is received on the connection.